# Can a PO box address be used as the registered address for a sole proprietorship in India?

Tags: privacy, business, india, sole-propietorship

Can a PO box be used as the registered address for a sole proprietorship? My business operates from home and it's totally online, and I prefer not to disclose my personal residence, while if my address of proof had to Aadhaar which I want to keep it private from exposing it to public databases.

Comment: Trademark is an entirely different matter from registered address.  The concerns mentioned the body of the question relate to registered address, not trademark.  I've removed the trademark aspects of the question.  If you're also interested in those, please ask a new question.  (Trademark would be implicated if you want to be able to advertise, for example, "buy your shoes from PO Box 42!  PO Box 42 sells the best shoes in town!"; or if you want to make a product called "PO Box 42" or labeled with the name "PO Box 42.")

Answer (score 1):

A physical address is [required](https://cleartax.in/s/physical-address-business-registration) for people or legal entities that do business in India to receive government correspondence and official documents. An option that's gaining popularity is virtual offices that give you a physical address. This is an option if you want to separate your business and personal affairs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing an alternative jurisdiction answer in case it is useful to others.

[united-kingdom](/questions/tagged/united-kingdom)[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)[northern-ireland](/questions/tagged/northern-ireland)[scotland](/questions/tagged/scotland)

Sole proprietorship businesses are not "registered" anywhere like companies are. So there is no requirement to have a "registered address". However, there are some requirements relating to business addresses for sole proprietorships which are set out in [Chapter 2 of Part 41 of the Companies Act 2006](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/46/part/41/chapter/2):

> 1200(1) This Chapter applies to an individual or partnership carrying
> on business in the United Kingdom under a business name.
>
> 1201(1) The “information required by this Chapter” is — [...] an
> address at which service of any document relating in any way to the
> business will be effective.
>
> 1201(2) If the individual or partnership has a place of business in
> the United Kingdom, the address must be in the United Kingdom.
>
> 1201(3) If the individual or partnership does not have a place of
> business in the United Kingdom, the address must be an address at
> which service of documents can be effected by physical delivery and
> the delivery of documents is capable of being recorded by the
> obtaining of an acknowledgement of delivery.
>
> 1202(1) A person to whom this Chapter applies must state the
> information required by this Chapter, in legible characters, on all —
> (a) business letters, (b) written orders for goods or services to be
> supplied to the business, (c) invoices and receipts issued in the
> course of the business, and (d) written demands for payment of debts
> arising in the course of the business.
>
> 1202(2) A person to whom this Chapter applies must secure that the
> information required by this Chapter is immediately given, by written
> notice, to any person with whom anything is done or discussed in the
> course of the business and who asks for that information.
>
> 1204(1) A person to whom this Chapter applies must, in any premises —
> (a) where the business is carried on, and (b) to which customers of
> the business or suppliers of goods or services to the business have
> access, display in a prominent position, so that it may easily be read
> by such customers or suppliers, a notice containing the information
> required by this Chapter.

This means that you can always use a PO box address in any scenario which isn't covered by the above requirements (e.g. to receive deliveries or customer service queries).

If you are using the address in a way which is covered by the requirements (e.g. it is the only address you are displaying on a business letter or you are providing it in response to a request made under the Act or displaying it in a notice at your premises under the Act) then you can only use a PO box address if it is compliant.

A PO box address will only be compliant if **either** you have a place of business in the UK and the PO box address is in the UK **or** you do not have a place of business in the UK and the PO box address is capable of physically receiving documents in a way which can be recorded (e.g. signed for).